# Updating Table In Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cqlsh

I have a following table structure in Cassandra :

```
CREATE TABLE ssession (
  sessionid text PRIMARY KEY,
  session_start_time timestamp,
  updated_time timestamp
);
```

`session_start_time` is time when a particular session becomes active and `update_time` is time till the user will be doing some activity.Here, `sessionid` and `session_start_time` will be inserted once and the `updated_time` keeps updating as the user is active.

`I want to include only sessionid as the primary key`.

Normal update statement will be :

```
UPDATE ssession SET session_start_time  = '2015-07-31 10:43:13+0530',
updated_time = '2015-07-31 10:43:13+0530' WHERE sessionid = '22_865624098';
```

Here, first time I'll insert same `session_start_time` and `updated_time` .But from next time I'll have to only update the `updated_time`.

And I need a single query to do so.Since, I'll be getting data continuously (using storm to process the data).

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you INSERT or UPDATE data (updates and inserts are the same in cassandra) you do not need to provide all columns.  If you just want to update the updated_time, your query should be:

```
UPDATE ssession SET updated_time = '2015-07-31 10:43:13+0530' WHERE sessionid = '22_865624098';
```

But it sounds like  you want to make sure that session_start_time is set the first time that sessionid is created and only the first time, correct?

What you could make use of [lightweight transactions](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0) and `if not exists` to create the data with session_start_time.  If there is already a row with that session_id, the insert will not be applied:

```
INSERT INTO ssession (sessionid, session_start_time, updated_time) values ('22_865624098', '2015-07-31 10:43:13+0530', '2015-07-31 10:43:13+0530') if not exists;
```

Cassandra returns a column `[applied]` in this case with a value of `true` or `false` if the insert was applied.  If `false` is returned, you can then simply run an update query that only updates `updated_time`:

```
UPDATE ssession set updated_time = '2015-07-31 10:43:14+0531' where sessionid = '22_865624098';
```

Note that lightweight transactions introduce some performance cost which is detailed in the article I linked above.  It uses 'SERIAL' consistency level which is a multi-phase QUORUM.   This is also a 'read-then-write' pattern, which is not going to be as fast as blindly writing the data.  You should test the performance of this solution and see if it is adequate for you.

Comment: alternatively you could cache locally what ssessions you've inserted and only provide session_start_time when it was not previously inserted.  If its not in the cache, you could look it up from cassandra and react whether or not the record is there.

Comment: Thanks man . I was thinking to do something like this. 

`if

UPDATE ssession set updated_time = '2015-07-31 10:43:14+0531' where sessionid = '22_865624098'
IF sessionid = ‘some-value’;

else

UPDATE ssession SET session_start_time  = '2015-07-31 10:43:13+0530',
updated_time = '2015-07-31 10:43:13+0530' WHERE sessionid = '22_865624098';`

Is it possible ?

Comment: This does not work as `PRIMARY KEY column 'sessionid' cannot have IF conditions`

Comment: What version of cassandra are you on?  The query I provided works for me locally using C* 2.1.8

Comment: I am using Cassandra 2.1.5 .

Comment: Cool, good to know.  What exact query are you trying to make that is failing?

Comment: `UPDATE ssession set updated_time = '2015-07-31 10:43:14+0531' where sessionid = '22_865624098' IF sessionid = ‘22_865624098’; `

I was trying this.But it fails because sessionid is a primary key.

Comment: Ah ok.  The 'IF' condition does not seem necessary there, because the where condition is already providing the session id.  If you want it to only update if sessionid exists, you can add 'IF EXISTS' instead.